# no restriction for refresh token lifetime span in identity server 4

Tags: .net, jwt, microservices, identityserver4

I used microservices, Currently am using JWT access token to access. But access token epired with certain time. To overcome this scenario I implemented refresh token to renew the expired access token. Now I want to implement no restriction for refresh token's lifetime span. How to achieve this?

Note: Am using Identity server 4 for JWT token generation

Answer (score 2):

As [documented](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html), set `RefreshTokenExpiration = Sliding` and `AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 0`.

The [DefaultRefreshToken](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultRefreshTokenService.cs#L111) service will accept that as indefinite slide. Relevant code:

```
// if absolute exp > 0, make sure we don't exceed absolute exp
// if absolute exp = 0, allow indefinite slide

var currentLifetime = refreshToken.CreationTime.GetLifetimeInSeconds(Clock.UtcNow.UtcDateTime);
var newLifetime = currentLifetime + client.SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime;

// zero absolute refresh token lifetime represents unbounded absolute lifetime
// if absolute lifetime > 0, cap at absolute lifetime
if (client.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime > 0 && newLifetime > client.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime)
{
    newLifetime = client.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime;
}
refreshToken.Lifetime = newLifetime;
```

Set `SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime` to a longer time, e.g. one month.

With those settings the user can refresh the token indefinitely, with one restriction: the user can't be inactive for more than a month.

You can adjust this value to an acceptable expiration time for you.

Comment: *user can refresh the token indefinitely, with one restriction: the user can't be inactive for more than a month* can be rephrased as *one month absolute exp*. so the answer is still the same: **that's impossible**. all beyond that is a kind of philosophy

Comment: @d_f One should wonder if a token should remain valid when a user is inactive for a longer period, a period that may be extended, e.g. to a year. Within normal usage the token will never expire, unlike a token where AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime > 0, as is the case in your answer. So the phrase that the token has a one month absolute expiration is not accurate.

Comment: in general I agree. I just doubt that sliding option is relevant at all for refresh. as I understand, it was designed for reusable tokens to minimize workload, but has someone reached any real improvement with that?.. question with no answer

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the code, validating refresh token lifetime, I see there just

```cs
return (now > creationTime.AddSeconds(lifetime));
```

So the answer is: it's not possible to set it unbounded.

Nevertheless you are free  to change the default value of 2592000 seconds / 30 days to something longer. Just set

```cs
AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = <your_desired_value>
```

in (each) client configuration in your Identityserver

Comment: can you explain me briefly or any examples or any references

Comment: updated the answer. don't know, how you configure your clients in idSrv, but in the simplest case you have there: `services.AddIdentityServer().AddInMemoryClients(someDelegate)` and inside the delegate a number of `new Client{ //setting props here }` calls. what you need is to set just one more property